# How can I quickly get today's date in a Lightning Component? (for use in an attribute)

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

In Visualforce, we could merge `{!TODAY()}` directly in the markup. What is the equivalent in a Lightning Component?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You create an attribute and initialize it using `$A.localizationService` in your controller.

Component:

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.init}" value="{!this}" />
   <aura:attribute name="today" type="Date" />
   <ui:outputDate value="{!v.today}" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    var today = $A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
    component.set('v.today', today);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Brian  `new Date()`  returns system date but not from logged in users timezone. `system.today()` in apex returns date from users timezone, is there any function like that in lightning component.

Comment: Please could you update your answer to use `$A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD")` instead of building the date manually

Comment: @WesNolte thank you for the input - updated! (and much cleaner)

Answer (score 2):

I have a slight modification to the JS you proposed, as you will run into comparison errors if the day is a single digit as well. Modifying the script like so fixed the problem:

```
var today = new Date();
var monthDigit = today.getMonth() + 1;
if (monthDigit <= 9) {
  monthDigit = '0' + monthDigit;
}
var dayDigit = today.getDate();
if(dayDigit <= 9){
  dayDigit = '0' + dayDigit;
}
component.set('v.today', today.getFullYear() + "-" + monthDigit + "-" + dayDigit);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use  below code as well.

```
//get today's date
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy + '-' + dd + '-' + mm;`
```

Answer (score -3):

As above
`//get today's date
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();`

however, if your local time format is different (e.g. UK), change the order.

```
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
```

You can also add a time if your attribute is of type datetime:

```
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + ', 11:45 pm GMT';
```

or

```
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + ', 21:45';
```

Not that Apex and Javastring formats are different.

apex format “yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss”

javascript format "2019-11-06T10:38:00.000Z"

so, if you are populating a datetime attribute, use

```
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + 'T09:30:00';
component.set('v.newEvent.StartDateTime', today);
```

Comment: I didn't vote this down, but without clarifying how you got `yyyy`, `mm`, and `dd` it is rather incomplete.

Comment: Please tell me why I have -2.
I'm new to this Exchange and thought I was being helpful.
More unexplained negatives and I shall leave the exchange and not bother.

Comment: Two people decided your answer is not useful. I am not sure why. Neither was me.